# How can I display decimal position based on my decimal position value?

Tags: c#, formatting

```
decimal value = 10;
int decimalPosition= 3; //this decimalPosition will be dynamically change.
decimal formatted = Math.Round(value, decimalPosition);
```

if decimalPosition =3;
 I need to display formatted value like : 10.000.

if decimalPosition =5;
 I need to display formatted value like : 10.00000.

Note: I must use `Round` function.

Comment: Why you must use `Round`?

Answer (score 2):

`decimal` value has no format assigned - it is just a numeric value. You can specify the format it's being printed out with, but you have to do it while printing or when the string is being created:

```
decimal value = 10;
int decimalPosition = 3; //this decimalPosition will be dynamically change.
decimal formatted = Math.Round(value, decimalPosition);

string format = string.Format("{{0:0.{0}}}", string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("0", decimalPosition).ToArray()));
string formattedString = string.Format(format, formatted);

Console.WriteLine(formattedString);
```

Prints `10.000` into console.

Another way of specifying format like that:

```
var format = string.Format("{{0:f{0}}}", decimalPosition);
```

Comment: Here hardcoded "0" value (Enumerable.Repeat("0", decimalPosition))

Comment: with out hard coding is it possible ?

Comment: This is not hardcoded `0`. It's custom numeric format string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Comment: string data = string.Format(format, formatted);

               decimal  value2 = Convert.ToDecimal(data);

Comment: Because  as I already said `decimal` is just a numeric value, it does not store anything about presentation ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:-

```
decimal.Round(yourValue, decimalPosition, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FORMATASNUMBER(Value, decimalPosition) instead of math.round

Sorry, I forgot it was c# not VB
But you can read about it here on MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.formatnumber(v=VS.80).aspx

The command is String.FormatNumber(blah blah blah)

and the ACTUAL declaration is...

```
public static string FormatNumber (
  Object Expression,
  [OptionalAttribute] int NumDigitsAfterDecimal,
  [OptionalAttribute] TriState IncludeLeadingDigit,
  [OptionalAttribute] TriState UseParensForNegativeNumbers,
  [OptionalAttribute] TriState GroupDigits
)
```

Comment: There is no such thing in C#

Comment: Click the link in the sample above and look at the c# sample. The evidence is there, its c#

Comment: Yes, there is `Strings.FormatNumber` method, but there is nothing called `FORMATASNUMBER`, which I claimed about.

Comment: Oh so that was the original comment? My bad, and my apologies :-)

Answer (score 0):

u can try it:--

```
decimal value = 10;
        int decimalPosition = 3; //this decimalPosition will be dynamically change.
        string position = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < decimalPosition; i++)
        {
            position += "0";
        }
        string newValue = value.ToString() + "." + position;
        decimal formatted = Convert.ToDecimal(newValue);
```

Comment: @Neeru Bindela u need not to use any additional function

Comment: @Neeru Bindela   Response.Write(formatted.ToString()); it is giving the same result u want

Comment: Yes But i need to store that value into decimal value